# Error enabling swagger with swashbucle

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying to create a WebApi project with a couple of simple controllers. If I call the methods using fiddler all is fine, however I prefer to use swashbuckle as it's a bit prettier.

However, with swashbuckle installed using the default configuration it isn't working.

When I navigate to 
http://localhost/api/mycontroller/swagger

it redirects to
http://localhost/api/mycontroller/swagger/ui/index

But then it just displays the following error:

> > <Error>
> >     <Message>
> >     No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/api/Management/swagger/ui/index'.
> >     </Message>
> >     <MessageDetail>
> >     No type was found that matches the controller named 'swagger'.
> >     </MessageDetail>
> >     </Error>

My routing is as follows:
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: get anywhere with this?

Comment: Got the same problem. Spent a couple of hours on this with no joy

Comment: Short answer is no. We think it's something to do with the service self hosting a signalr hub and that is messing with the routing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We found a very simple solution to our issue.

When swagger was added to the project it automatically updated the Bootstrapper.cs within App_Start, and it looked like this:

```
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    UnityConfig.Register(config, container);
    SignalRConfig.Register(app, container);
    SwaggerConfig.Register(config);
```

Simply moving swagger to the top of the list allowed it to register it's routes correctly before the web api routes:

```
    SwaggerConfig.Register(config); // Swagger must be the first thing in this sequence or it just does not work...
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    UnityConfig.Register(config, container);
    SignalRConfig.Register(app, container);
```

Just posting this in the hope that it helps someone else.

Comment: LOL! You made my day! :) I was fighting it for a whole weekend with no result. Finally I found this solution and it works like a charm :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, we are only using attribute routing so this may not apply to everyone.

By default the WebApiConfig looks like this:

```
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
```

If you remove the section for to MapHttpRoute for the default routing and just have:

config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

It works like a champ!!! I tried following the [FAQ](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#troubleshooting-and-faqs) regarding fixing it but this was the only thing that worked.  Also another item to consider is that I only needed Swashbuckle.Core.